# How to calculate meters per second speed when i have distance in meters and time in minutes

Tags: kinematics, speed, distance

It might be a simple formula but I want to confirm it so can you please tell me how can I find speed in meters per second when I have Distance = 7720298 meters and total time 320941.03 minutes. How will I find the speed in meters per second.
Thanks

Comment: 1 minute is 60 seconds. Average speed is distance by time. (I find this question too trivial. Its strongly recommended you google such questions.)

Answer (score 1):

If you take the ratio of the values you have, you will have the velocity in meters per minute, right?

Then, to obtain the value in meters per second, you just have to convert that time from minutes to seconds. You can do that by multiplying by 60, because 1 minute is equal to 60 seconds.

Therefore, your time is now $320941.03 \text{ minutes} \times \dfrac{60 \text{ seconds}}{\text{ minute}} = 19256461.8 \text{ seconds}$.

Which allows us to do the final calculation, giving velocity as

$$ \dfrac{7720298 \text{ meters}}{19256461.8 \text{ seconds}} \approx 0,40092 \text{ meters per second}$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the speed in m/s, you will need to have a distance measurement in meters (which you already have), and a time measurement in seconds (which you don't).

You can change a measurement from one unit to another version of that unit by multiplying by 1. Multiplying a number by 1 doesn't change the value, which is why changing units doesn't change the value of the measurement, just the way it's expressed.  The trick is choosing what "version" of 1 to multiply by.

Here's what I mean:

$$320941.03 ~\rm min = 1 * 320941.03 ~\rm min$$
We will choose $\frac{60 ~\rm s}{1 ~\rm min}$ as the version of 1 we will multiply by.  $\frac{60 ~\rm s}{1 ~\rm min} = 1$ because dividing two things that are equal gives you 1.
$$320941.03 ~\rm min = \frac{60 ~\rm s}{1 ~\rm min} * 320941.03 ~\rm min$$
$$320941.03 ~\rm min = \frac{60 ~\rm s \cdot 320941.03 ~\rm min}{1 ~\rm min}$$
We can "cancel out" the unit $\rm min$, because it appears in the numerator and denominator
$$320941.03 ~\rm min = \frac{60~\rm s \cdot 320941.03}{1}$$
$$320941.03 ~\rm min = 60 \cdot 320941.03 ~\rm s$$
$$320941.03 ~\rm min = 19256461.8 ~\rm s$$

---

Then, to find the speed, you can use the definition of average speed:
$$v = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$
$$v = \frac{7720298 ~\rm m}{19256461.8 ~\rm s}$$
$$v = 0.4 ~\rm m/s$$

Answer (score -1):

It's an easy method. You need to calculate m/s, when you have distance in meter and time in seconds. Just use the simple relation. 1 minutes equals 60 seconds. That means 320941.03 minutes equals 320941.03*60 s. Which is 19256461.8 seconds. Now use the formula, speed equals distance per time.
i.e,
v = s/t
  = 7720298/19256461.8
  = 0.40091986161237574807226527980337 m/s
so, the speed(velocity) in m/s is 0.4009m/s.